# Не формируется GET запрос из формы

Tags: html, python

Вот код формы

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary expand_graph" style="margin-top: 10px; 
margin-left: 20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data- 
whatever="@mdo">Expand Graph</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Expand Your Graph</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form action="expand_graph" method="GET">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-form-label">Search:</label>
              <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" id="search_expand">
              <label class="col-form-label">Keywords:</label>
              <input name="keywords" type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords_expand">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

На сервере видно что запрос по адресу проходит успешно.

```
GET /graph/BuildGraph/expand_graph HTTP/1.1 200
```

Если в адресной строке ввести http://127.0.0.1:8000/graph/BuildGraph/expand_graph?search=python&keywords=django то на сервер приходит все как нужно. С формы отправить не получается ни GET'ом ни POST'ом. Возможно нужно ставить обработчик модальных событий. Это же модальное окно. У него есть какие нибудь особенности в плане отправки форм?

Comment: <form action="expand_graph" method="POST">

Comment: Ну так get запрос должен все равно с формы корректно отправиться на сервер с переданными параметрами. Если в адресной строке ввести http://127.0.0.1:8000/graph/BuildGraph/expand_graph?search=python&keywords=django то на сервер приходит все как нужно. С формы отправить не получается ни GET'ом ни POST'ом. Возможно нужно ставить обработчик модальных событий. Это же модальное окно. У него есть какие нибудь особенности в плане отправки форм?